# Pile of stones. Probability.

Tags: probability

Given a pile of stones. Every stone has a unique (different from others) weight. The $10$ easiest stones  form $40\%$ of the total weight and $5$ most heavy-weight stones form $25\%$ of total weight. We randomly take one stone from the pile. What is the probability that the chosen stone will be the easiest (i.e belongs to the first $40\%$) ?

I tried to use the law of total probability and and considered three hypotheses:

$H_1$ --- the stone was from group of the  easiest stones  ( $40\%$);

$H_2$ --- the stone was from group of the  most heavy-weight stones stones  ( $25\%$);

$H_3$ --- the stone was from the rest part of the pile.  ( $35\%$).

But in this case  I don't use the information: given $10$ and $5.$

Comment: Being the lightest stone and belonging to the "first $40\%$"  of all stones is not the same thing.

Comment: well..yes, seems you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average weight of the 10 lightest stones is 4% of the total pile weight. The 5 heaviest stones have an average weight of 5 %. The remaining unknown number of stones must have an average between those values.
So:
$$
4<\frac{35}{n}<5 \text{ with } n\in\mathbb{N}
$$ 
With $n=8$ you get the probability:
$$
p=\frac{10}{10 + 8 + 5}=\frac{10}{23}
$$